# Finding two inequivalent closed, non-exact $1$-forms on $T = S^1 \times S^1$: second check

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

This is a follow up on my previous question. I would like to test whether I understand the first part of the answer given to me there by rewriting it in my own words.

> Please could someone tell me if this is correct?

(Like before I'd like you to be meticulous/nitpicky.)

My goal was to find two non-equivalent closed non-exact smooth $1$-forms on $T=S^1 \times S^1$.

We know that the angle form $d\theta$ on $S^1$ is closed but not exact. If we let $U = S^1 - N$ and $V = S^1 - S$ where $N$ and $S$ are the north and southpole respectively then $(U\times U, (\theta_U, \varphi_U)$ and $(V \times V, (\theta_V,\varphi_V)) $ are two smooth charts for $T$ such that on $U\cap V$ we have $d \theta_U = d\theta_V$ and $d\varphi_U = d \varphi_V$.

We denote by $d\theta$ and $d\varphi$ the differential $1$-forms that agree with the corresponding $1$-forms $d \theta_U, d\theta_V$ and $d\varphi_U, d \varphi_V$ on $U$ and $V$ respectively.

We now claim that $d\theta, d\varphi$ are closed but not exact and that they do not differ by an exact $1$-form.

Since for this angular parametrisation one of the three Euclidean coordinates $x,y,z$ is constant both $d\theta$ and $d \varphi$ are an expression of the form ${x dy - y dx \over x^2 + y^2} $ so that it is clear that they are closed.

To see that they are not exact we use the curves 
$$ \gamma (t) = (t,0)$$ and
$$ \gamma' (t) = (0,t)$$

We have

$$ \oint_\gamma d \theta = \int_0^{2\pi} (1,0)\cdot(1,0) dt = 2 \pi$$
and similarly for $d\varphi$. Hence by Stokes' theorem both forms are not exact.

Finally, assume that $d\theta - d\varphi$ was exact. Then by Stokes' theorem we'd have

$$ \oint_\gamma d\theta - d\varphi = 0$$

but we just saw that this is not the case hence $d\theta$ and $d \varphi$ do not differ by an exact $1$-form and hence are not equivalent.

Comment: You have never defined $\phi_U, \phi_V$. Moreover a differential form on $U\times U$ is not a pair of differental forms on $U$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg $\theta_{U,V}$ and $\varphi_{U,V}$ are the angle functions on $S^1 - \ast$. I don't understand your comment about pairs because I don't use any pairs of differential forms in my question... could you elaborate?

Comment: Your notation is not clear: as far as I understand $\theta_U=\varphi_U$, so that the use of two different letters is unnecessary. What are for example $\theta_U(1,0)$ and  $\varphi_U (1,0)$ (Supposing that $S^1$ is given by $x^2+y^2=1$ ) ? If you don't believe these charts are equal, at what point would  they  have   different values?

Answer (score 1):

That all looks pretty decent to me. As an alternative, you could just say that given a 1-form $\alpha$ on the first factor and a function $f$ on the second factor, you can define a 1-form on the product, 
$$
\beta_p(v) = f(p) \alpha(D\pi_1(p)[v])
$$
where $\pi_1$ is the projection on the first factor. A natural name for $\beta$ is $\alpha \times f$. So the two things you've got are
$$
d\theta \times 1 \\
1 \times d\phi
$$
Your proof of non-exactness still applies. I just didn't have to define the 1-forms via charts, which is a little nicer.

(You still need to prove closed-ness, but it's probably not a bad idea to convince yourself that $d(\alpha \times \beta)$, where $\times$ is properly generalized, is something like $(d\alpha) \times \beta \pm \alpha \times (d\beta)$, and then the result follows.)